# (ionic-capacitor) I can't access to Apple Login data

Tags: ios, authentication, ionic-framework, mobile, capacitor

I have an App that were built in Ionic Cordova. Recently I change it to Ionic Capacitor. With this change, i've been trying to incorporate an Apple Login but it doesn't working correctly: Apple returns the token but with empty data (email, familyName, etc, all of these returns null). What would be happening?

This is my implementation:

```
   openAppleSignIn() {
    const { SignInWithApple } = Plugins;
    SignInWithApple.Authorize()
      .then(async (res) => {
        const respuesta =JSON.stringify(res.response)
        
          let obje = JSON.parse(respuesta)
          //alert(obje.identityToken)
       //alert(res.response.email)
          //alert(JSON.stringify(obje.email))
          
        
        if (obje && obje.identityToken) {
          this.user = obje;

          this.server.providerLogin({profile:{email:obje.email,first_name:obje.givenName,last_name:obje.familyName,name:obje.givenName,given_name:obje.givenName,family_name:obje.familyName}}, 'Google').subscribe((response2:any) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify({profile:{email:obje.email,first_name:obje.givenName,last_name:obje.familyName,name:obje.givenName,given_name:obje.givenName,family_name:obje.familyName}}))
            if(response2.msg != "done")
            {
              this.presentToast(response2.msg, 'warning');
            }
            else
            {
              if(response2.user_id){
                localStorage.setItem('user_id',response2.user_id);
                this.events.publish('user_login', response2.user_id);
                this.presentToast("Bienvenue !", 'secondary');
                this.nav.back();
              }
              else{
                this.presentToast("Une erreur s'est porduite. Merci de bien vouloir réessayer.", 'danger');
              }
            }
    
          });
          
          //console.log('este es el user',this.user)
        } else {
          this.presentAlert();
        }
      })
      .catch((response) => {
        this.presentAlert();
      });
  }
```

Comment: i got such problem before, it sometimes return data and much times empty on the same email... so the problem was in the plugin itself... try to use other plugin... there are several apple login plugins that should do it for u... but before changing plugin, make sure u granted all the permissions needed from apple connect and from XCode for apple plugin to work correctly...

Comment: I have the same problem. By using simulator with iOS 13.7 or below it works. But on iOS14 or iOS 15, no data is given back by the call to Apple, even if authorization is granted

Comment: Any update on this? I also recently moved to capacitor from cordova but apple login is returning empty data. I tried capacitor/core Plugin as well as capacitor-community/apple-signin plugin